# I get error when I try to run hadoop jar to remote node

Tags: hadoop

I get this error when I try to run hadoop jar to remote node, I have one master node and few slaves node in multi-cluster. I have two problems

1. When I run `start-all.sh` it ask me for password even though I create ssh auth and I can ssh to remote and localhost without password. For example if if run start-all.ssh, I get user@mycomputername: password, but when I keep hit enter, all the daemons will run after all.
2. is the below error.

   ```
    15/01/20 08:53:01 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:utra cause:java.net.ConnectException: Call to user/------:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to user/------:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:111`enter code here`8)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
        at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:583)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2200(Client.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1093)
        ... 34 more
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this command as root:

```
chown -R hadoop:root /usr/local/hadoop
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution to users who might not be too familiar with `chown` and why this solves the problem?

Comment: this set  appropriate permissions to  files

Comment: It says: chown: invalid user: `hadoop:root' , when logged as root@user

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. By the way i created new user granted All, then i installed hadoop using user account, also when i ssh between my nodes i am not using root@mycomputername,

Comment: i am using mynewuser@mycomputername. ssh is working but when i run start-all.sh then the password will pop up for each node, but i just keep press enter, then when i use jps, i can see all my daemens. one thing i realized, the master node is not start the cluster nodes (datanode and tasktracker), i have to do it manually, means i have to ssh to every node and start the datannode and tasktracker, which is lot of work.

Comment: in my case hadoop is the user that I created in your case I guess it is your new user and may be there is an issue with your configuration because it is not normal follow this link (http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) it may help you